# How do i insert into a map the values i get from findAllBy?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to insert into a map the values i get from a `findAllBy` method.

I have tried to use the `each` function and then `put` to insert the values into the map like so:

```
def carousel
def links = [:]
carousel = Carousel.findAllByLang(lang)
carousel.each{
    links.put(
        "image" = it.urlImage
        "url" = it.urlLink
    )
}
```

I am trying to reproduce what this code does but without the hard coded urls:

```
links = [
    [
        image: 'https://first.url.jpg',
        url  : 'https://www.first.link.com'
    ],
    [
        image: 'https://second.url.jpg',
        url  : 'https://www.second.link.com'
    ],

    ...
]
```

but i am not getting the expected results. The contents of the carousel object are fine, i am just not being able to insert the values inside the map as desired.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main issue is that i didn't have a really good idea of the data structures i was working with.
This solved it:

```groovy
def carousel
def links = []
carousel = Carousel.findAllByLangAndActive(lang,true,[sort:"sequence", order: "asc"])
carousel.each {
    def map = ["image":it.urlImage, "url":it.urlLink]
    links << map
}
```

Comment: You can shorten this a bit: `def links = carousel.collect{ [image: it. urlImage, url: it.urlLink] }`

Comment: this answer does NOT match your question. Originally you wanted to fill up the map, and here you are filling up the list